# How do I clear cache using an SQL query?

Tags: caching

After a module update, my site has become unusable, and only shows a php error message.
I tried circumventing the problem with `drush cc`, but that didn't help.

Also tried with a custom php script but that has issues finding my `DRUPAL_ROOT`

I just want to clear the cache tables from Drupal 7 directly on the mysql server, but I'm unsure which tables should be cleared for that and especially which I should not clear.

Do I just need to clear all the `[SITE-PREFIX_]cache*` tables?

Comment: Could you please add the query you used?

Comment: actually I was looking for a Query to use with something like: `EMPTY WHERE tablename IS LIKE 'prefix_chache%' but in the end I just used phpmyadmin to drop the tables because I couldn't find such a query.

Comment: Just as a note, make sure you've run the database updates either through `drush updb` or from the admin interface, or by simply going to `/update.php` after a module/core update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any well written module that has a cache, should prefix it with cache, meaning that the answer to your question is "Yes".

In the odd event that a module caches data somewhere else, you can check your modules for implementations of [hook_flush_caches](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_flush_caches/7), and see what they remove.

Answer (score 34):

Yes, you can simply clear (`TRUNCATE`) all `cache*` tables.

This worked well for me:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE cache;
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_block;
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_bootstrap;
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_field;
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_filter;
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_form;
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_image;
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_menu;
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_page;
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_path;
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_token;
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_update;
```

If you use drush, run `drush sql-cli` and paste the above in there.

These commands might not clear all cache tables of your specific site but it can help fix some errors. Afterwards you can try `drush cc all` to clear the rest.

Comment: It's also easy to add extra TRUNCATE queries for any additional cache_ tables that might be present on your site.

Answer (score 15):

To clear all cache tables run this command in your server terminal.

```
# Truncate cache tables in MySQL regardless of the active cache backend
echo "SHOW TABLES LIKE 'cache%'" | $(drush sql-connect) | tail -n +2 | xargs -L1 -I% echo "TRUNCATE TABLE %;" | $(drush sql-connect) -v
```

this will loop through all cache tables and truncate them in one command.

Comment: This works, tested it and all is zero.

Comment: This helped me get a site running again when it had unclear "Class not found" errors.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, I like your one-liner solution better than the accepted answer, because it's more flexible: the pattern catches custom/contrib cache tables as well, not only the hard-coded lists.

Answer (score 4):

For me (Drupal 9.1.3) - works below:

```
TRUNCATE cache_bootstrap;                  
TRUNCATE cache_config;                     
TRUNCATE cache_container;                  
TRUNCATE cache_data;                       
TRUNCATE cache_default;                    
TRUNCATE cache_discovery;                  
TRUNCATE cache_dynamic_page_cache;         
TRUNCATE cache_entity;                     
TRUNCATE cache_menu;                       
TRUNCATE cache_page;                       
TRUNCATE cache_render;                     
TRUNCATE cache_toolbar;                    
TRUNCATE cachetags;
```

After TRUNCATE this tables clear browser's history. That's all.

Answer (score 3):

You can either TRUNCATE/DELETE each table separately which starts from `cache_` like:

```
DELETE FROM cache;
DELETE FROM cache_block;
```

and so on (check via `drush sqlq "SHOW TABLES LIKE 'cache_%'"`).

Or generate query with list of tables and pass into drush to truncate them, e.g.:

```
echo "SHOW TABLES LIKE 'cache%'" | $(drush sql-connect) | tail -n +2 | xargs -L1 -I% echo "DELETE FROM %;" | $(drush sql-connect) -v
```

or:

```
echo "SELECT CONCAT('DELETE FROM ', GROUP_CONCAT(TABLE_NAME SEPARATOR ';DELETE FROM ') , ' cache;' ) AS statement FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'cache_%'" | drush sqlc --extra=--skip-column-names | drush sqlc
```

#### Memcache

If you're using memcached, you also need to flush the caches there, e.g. (Bash syntax):

```
echo flush_all > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/11211
```

Answer (score 1):

`drush cr` and/or `drush cc all` is supposed to clear all caches, but indeed some cache tables do not get cleared.
The following (simplified) command does truncate all caches:

```
drush sql-query "SHOW TABLES LIKE 'cache%'" | while read table; do drush sql-query "TRUNCATE $table"; done;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can import you mysql dump with already truncated `cache*` tables:

```
gunzip -c ~/database.sql.gz | grep -v 'INSERT INTO `cache'| mysql --user=root drupal
```

Answer (score 0):

JFR in this article an other flexible pattern-based solution is offered in a form of raw SQL-query, but was not working for me as good as Mohammad's: https://thebarton.org/clear-drupal-cache-sql-query/