# caching issue after updating records into database

Tags: caching

I've developed *leave management* in drupal 7 but facing an issue. When leave balance is updated due to calculations then it not shows right value from database due to drupal caching. Once I clean all caches then it shows right values. Is there any way to stop caching or update caching?

Please do some help.

Comment: did you add cache in your module after update DB

Comment: No, I've not used any modules for it.

Comment: Any help for this guyz?

Answer (score 1):

Any well written module that has a cache, should prefix it with cache, meaning that the answer to your question is "Yes".

In the odd event that a module caches data somewhere else, you can check your modules for implementations of [hook_flush_caches](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_flush_caches/7), and see what they remove.

[Reference](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21434/how-to-clear-cache-using-an-sql-query-in-drupal-7) by Letharion

Comment: Hello Adi, I've used webformas leave application form and for leave balance I've created one field to Configuration->people->account settings->manage fields. How can I implement this answer to here?