# How to uncache Commerce cart?

Tags: 7, caching, commerce

In Drupal 7 Commerce, I am running into an issue with this workflow:

1. Add item to cart
2. Apply qualifying coupon. Correct discount is taken off item
3. Add new item to cart with qualifying discount.
4. Old discount in order shown UNTIL you reload the page 2 times.

Basically I am adding a coupon to the cart at the `/checkout/%` page

It seems like the block or view is being cached.

What is the best means to uncache the block?

I have tried using:

```
cache_clear_all('shopping_cart_summary_new', 'cache_views_data', TRUE);
```

as well as:

```
$order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
commerce_coupon_commerce_cart_order_refresh($order_wrapper);
```

Comment: What have you tried? Clearing cache from Drupal, `drush cc all`? Restarting `memcached`? Any other [caches](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/124707/1908)? Can you list all your relevant modules? What do you use for discounts?

Comment: How are you adding the coupon is it in the cart page, or on another block?

Comment: @nvahalik I am adding a coupon to the cart on the /checkout/ORDERID page

Comment: @kenorb I have tried using cache_clear_all('shopping_cart_summary_new', 'cache_views_data', TRUE); as well as
$order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
 commerce_coupon_commerce_cart_order_refresh($order_wrapper);

Comment: Try [clearing your all your `cache_%` tables](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/21434/1908) manually and see if that helps.

Comment: @kenorb Even if that works, I need a means of ensuring if a user adds a coupon to their cart and then changes the cart, the correct discount is applied

Comment: @Matt Which module do you use for discounts? Do you have any screenshots that you can provide?

Comment: @kenorb I used the Commerce Coupon module

Comment: @Matt Did cache clearing worked temporary?

Comment: Is the discount an order or a product discount? What version of the discount/coupon modules are you using? An export of your discount would be helpful.

Comment: So I just tried a similar operation on Commerce Kickstart 1.x with the latest coupons and discounts module: Added the product to the cart, added a coupon (tied to a product discount), and then opened another product page in another tab. After adding it once again to the cart and refreshing the checkout page 1 time, the cart was correct. Perhaps you're using some sort of AJAX functionality? Regardless, this likely goes beyond the limits of SE and needs to be reproducible.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think it was a Rule malfunctioning