# fatal error when i want to disable apachesolr module

Tags: search

I see an error when i want disable apachesolr module.
what should i do?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated:

Point from @kiamlaluno is correct, the apachesolr_stats has apachesolr listed as a dependency. Therefore, in order to disable the apachesolr, you should first disable the apachesolr_stats (and possibly other dependent modules).

I suspect that this issue comes from cached blocks, when I look at the trace you posted. Try to clear the cache and/or disable the apachesolr_stats block before trying to disable the apachesolr module.

Original:

You should try to disable the apachesolr_stats module first.
If you are using drush, this would be the command:

```
drush dis -y apachesolr_stats
```

If you don't have drush, you can also use MySQL/PHPMyAdmin commands, here are some links with examples:

Disabling modules:
https://www.drupal.org/node/157632

Clearing cache:
[How do I clear cache using an SQL query?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21434/how-to-clear-cache-using-an-sql-query-in-drupal-7)  [if that answer works for you, you can upvote ;) ]
https://www.drupal.org/documentation/clearing-rebuilding-cache

Good luck!

Comment: Should not Drupal avoid the user disables a module that has depending modules enabled? As far as I remember, I cannot even select a module from which other modules depend on, to disable it.

Comment: my drupal only shows this error, not anything else. I don't know how i can install drush on windows. is there another way ?

Comment: Hey Hamed, I updated my answer, have a look.

Comment: thank you stefanos. sorry for long delay. now my problem is finding a complete solution to install drush on windows 10. I searched very very much.

Comment: Hey Hamed, no problem, it's good to see you coming back to this. Let's try to solve this. About drush, I open a new question "Drush on Windows 10", if there is not one there already. For this question, you can also disable a module and clear the cache tables from your MySQL (phpmyadmin), I updated my answer.

Comment: A small error in the last comment. I meant to say "I would open a new question..."