# Cannot change an existing field's type. in field_update_field() line 240 of field.crud.inc

Tags: entities, database

My instance of drupal is throwing an error. The file that is throwing the error is `modules/field/field.crud.inc`

The error is

> FieldException: Cannot change an existing field's type. in field_update_field() (line 240 of modules/field/field.crud.inc).

A local var dump displays the following results.

Variable `$field`

```
array (
  'active' => 1,
  'cardinality' => 1,
  'deleted' => 0,
  'entity_types' => 
  array (
  ),
  'field_name' => 'field_address',
  'foreign keys' => 
  array (
    'format' => 
    array (
      'columns' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'format',
      ),
      'table' => 'filter_format',
    ),
  ),
  'indexes' => 
  array (
    'format' => 
    array (
      0 => 'format',
    ),
  ),
  'locked' => 0,
  'module' => 'text',
  'settings' => 
  array (
    'max_length' => 255,
  ),
  'translatable' => 0,
  'type' => 'text',
)
```

Variable `$prior_field`

```
array (
  'translatable' => '0',
  'entity_types' => 
  array (
  ),
  'settings' => 
  array (
  ),
  'storage' => 
  array (
    'type' => 'field_sql_storage',
    'settings' => 
    array (
    ),
    'module' => 'field_sql_storage',
    'active' => '1',
    'details' => 
    array (
      'sql' => 
      array (
        'FIELD_LOAD_CURRENT' => 
        array (
          'field_data_field_address' => 
          array (
            'country' => 'field_address_country',
            'administrative_area' => 'field_address_administrative_area',
            'sub_administrative_area' => 'field_address_sub_administrative_area',
            'locality' => 'field_address_locality',
            'dependent_locality' => 'field_address_dependent_locality',
            'postal_code' => 'field_address_postal_code',
            'thoroughfare' => 'field_address_thoroughfare',
            'premise' => 'field_address_premise',
            'sub_premise' => 'field_address_sub_premise',
            'organisation_name' => 'field_address_organisation_name',
            'name_line' => 'field_address_name_line',
            'first_name' => 'field_address_first_name',
            'last_name' => 'field_address_last_name',
            'data' => 'field_address_data',
          ),
        ),
        'FIELD_LOAD_REVISION' => 
        array (
          'field_revision_field_address' => 
          array (
            'country' => 'field_address_country',
            'administrative_area' => 'field_address_administrative_area',
            'sub_administrative_area' => 'field_address_sub_administrative_area',
            'locality' => 'field_address_locality',
            'dependent_locality' => 'field_address_dependent_locality',
            'postal_code' => 'field_address_postal_code',
            'thoroughfare' => 'field_address_thoroughfare',
            'premise' => 'field_address_premise',
            'sub_premise' => 'field_address_sub_premise',
            'organisation_name' => 'field_address_organisation_name',
            'name_line' => 'field_address_name_line',
            'first_name' => 'field_address_first_name',
            'last_name' => 'field_address_last_name',
            'data' => 'field_address_data',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'foreign keys' => 
  array (
  ),
  'indexes' => 
  array (
  ),
  'id' => '132',
  'field_name' => 'field_address',
  'type' => 'text',
  'module' => 'text',
  'active' => '1',
  'locked' => '0',
  'cardinality' => '1',
  'deleted' => '0',
  'columns' => 
  array (
    'value' => 
    array (
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => NULL,
      'not null' => false,
    ),
    'format' => 
    array (
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => 255,
      'not null' => false,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Were you trying to change a field's type and then got this error? Or did it just appear out of the blue?

Comment: It's a long standing issue that I have not been able to resolve.

Comment: please provide more info, like an answer to my question above for example, or remove this question. without more data, this question is too specific to your environment and it's very difficult to resolve on this forum

Comment: I think it simple enough to solve. It has something to do with the database and the field causing a collision, my question is what fields is it and why. I can provide more details as long as they are related to the problem.

Comment: Fair enough. Do you get the error message when you view every page, or only on a specific content type?

Comment: Only happens sometimes when I flush the cache for the entire site. Might have something to do with the rebuild process for drupal core.

Comment: My guess is that you have some change to the text field setting in your cache and when you try to clear the cache, it tries to update the field which is forbidden because it already has data in it. Therefore the cache clear fails. You might want to try on your DEV copy to manually flush the cache tables like in the second answer [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21434/how-to-clear-cache-using-an-sql-query-in-drupal-7) using SQL Truncate to clear all the cache tables... hopefully that will clear it out.

Comment: Are you using a debug? Try set a breakpoint where error occur and check the stack, this will give some hint. Of course maybe there are more than 1 calls to `field_update_field()`, but when you pass you will see the error.

Comment: This error occurs most commonly when Features is installed, and the definition of the field in a feature conflicts with that in the DB. Is that possible here?

Comment: Solution of the problem described herein:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1201898

Comment: Linking to a conversation about a possible solution is not the answer. I tried to truncate the tables and then see if that cleared the issue with no success.  See new comment about the drush command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution to this problem, i'm going to also document how I found the solution.

If you see the message that something went wrong stop and look at the logs that Drupal reports back to you and take the time to read them.

In this example I was getting this error due to a specific module and when Drupal was faulting out the module `basic_cart_order` was the last one to be rebuilding based on the logs.

Now that I knew what module was faulting out it was time to find out why. I found the fields that where causing the message `field_address` and I looked within in that module for that value.

```
grep -R "field_address"
```

That brought me over to this file

`sites/all/modules/basic_cart/basic_cart_order/basic_cart_order.features.field_base.inc`

I opened up that file and made a couple of changes to all the fields that where causing a conflict to the database. You can find all the fields that cause the error in your log message. I added a prefix to all the fields with `basic_cart_order`.

*This fixed the problem down to the line that was throwing the error.*