# Moving from subdomain to top level, link/image paths incorrect after manual edit

Tags: caching, migrations, .htaccess, configuration

TL;DR Filepaths contain old subdomain prefix after find replace database and site code, can't determine cause.

I have a hosted site on `mywebsite.com/drupal`, I want to move it to my computer `localhost`.

I have a LAMP stack and I compress and download the contents of `mywebsite.com/drupal` and export its mysql database, `mydb.sql`, using phpmyadmin.

I uncompress and place all the files from `mywebsite.com/drupal` in `/var/www/html/`, I create a new database, `local.db`, locally and import `mydb.sql`. I edit `/var/www/html/sites/default/settings.php` $databases array and connect it to `local.db`.

I ensure all files permissions are correct by running

```
chown user:user -R /var/www/html/
chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/
```

I can then access my site using a browser and going to localhost, however the images are missing none of the links work.

Initially I thought the cause was that there are many instances in the database and my site code still containing filepaths with the subdomain `/drupal/` prefix, images for example:

```
src="/drupal/sites/default/files/inline-images..."
```

When I move the site to `localhost`, it should just be:

```
src="/sites/default/files/inline-images..."
```

To solve this, I did a find `/drupal/` and replace `/` in my database, reimported it and then used `grep -rl '/drupal/' ./ | xargs sed -i 's_/drupal/_/_g'` on `/var/www/html/`.

I thought this would have resolved the problem, however when I access `localhost`, the problem persists, images and links still contain the `/drupal/` prefix in their filepaths. I've read on a few migration guides that I should flush all caches on the drupal backend before moving  (which I did) and also potentially [flush the mysql cache](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21434/how-do-i-clear-cache-using-an-sql-query/126552#126552) using phpmyadmin, however I get an error `#1146 - Table 'mydb.cache' doesn't exist` when I try to execute the truncate commands.

Other guides mention `.htaccess`, which I copied over from `mysite.com/drupal`, admittedly I don't understand everything inside it deeply, but I can't find any code which is prefixing filepaths with `/drupal/`.

As a sanity check, I created `/var/www/html/drupal/` and copied my site and then everything works fine.

I don't understand, how can the filepaths remain the same when I have changed all instances in the database and site code? I think there is something easy I'm missing but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Is this Drupal 7 or 8? Not sure that it matters, but take a look at around line 102 of your .htaccess file, should look like this:

```
# Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
# VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
# For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
# modify the following line:
# RewriteBase /drupal
```

The issue you describes sounds like the RewriteBase is incorrect. What does your .htaccess say?

Can you also tell me what your settings.php file has for the base URL value?

```
# $base_url = 'http://www.example.com';  // NO trailing slash!
```

Comment: I'm using Drupal 8, in .htaccess `RewriteBase` is commented out, I tried uncommenting and setting to `RewriteBase /`, no luck. My settings.php does not have a `$base_url`, the closest I find is a line `# $settings['file_public_base_url'] = 'http://downloads.example.com/files';`, which is commented out.

Comment: Ok, thanks for telling me about the Drupal version. Can you post the contents of your .htaccess (removing anything you don't want public). I am mostly concerned with the redirect settings. starting at:

Comment: Starting at line 69 ending somewhere around line 121.

Comment: Looked into this a little bit more, I'm thinking it's related to a [Core D8 issues described here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2753591)

Comment: My [.htaccess](http://pastebin.com/k9H3f4js). In regards to the Core D8 issue you linked, I see comment #10 suggests [this patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/fix_mismatch_of-2753591-9.patch). Forgive my naivete, but how does one apply such a patch? Navigate to that file in the core, remove the - lines and add the + lines of code?

Comment: I want to warn you, patching core is _usually_ not a great idea. If a new drupal release is pushed out prior to this patch going in to core, your updates will be gone, and you will be back to square one. That being said, yes, you are basically going to remove the - lines and add the + lines.

Always make a back up of the files you change if you are not using version control (like git). Do NOT patch a live site without testing.

There are automated ways to apply patches. You can read more about those here:
 - https://www.drupal.org/patch/apply
 - https://www.drupal.org/node/534548

Comment: I appreciate all your help and I understand your warnings about patching core. However, doesn't this issue ultimately have to do with some $base variable being incorrectly set to /drupal/ instead of /? Can't I just change this variable somewhere? I attempted to do this with my manual editing, I'm still perplexed as to how it persistently gives the wrong path, as I'm fairly confident I've changed all instances of the incorrect path.

Comment: I think the issue I linked to explains that in some instances, the replacement for the $base_path global in Drupal 7 that was created for Drupal 8 does not work correctly. I think you are describing one of those instances. I unfortunately do not have a tone of Drupal 8 experience yet.